# How to create webhook while creating/updating new product/attribute in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I want create a webhook when adding a  product or an attribute or updating an attribute.
For example :

```
function add_this_to_new_products( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    $defaults = array ( 'shopid' => array (
                                  'name' => 'shopid',
                                  'value' => 'mahdi',
                                  'position' => 1,
                                  'is_visible' => 1,
                                  'is_variation' => 1,
                                  'is_taxonomy' => 1,
                               ),

    );

update_post_meta( $post->ID , '_product_attributes', $defaults );

}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'add_this_to_new_products', 10, 3 );
```

Or

```
function add_this_to_new_products( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    $defaults = get_bloginfo();
update_post_meta( $post->ID , '_product_attributes', $defaults );


}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'add_this_to_new_products', 10, 3 );
```

But none of these works. please guide me. Thank you

Comment: I'm kinda not sure about the concept of your question. You topic is ***How to create new attribute in woocommerce with webhook automatically*** and in your question you said ***you want make a webhook when adding a product or an attribute or updating an attribute***. As far I know webhook sends push notification, you can't create something with it. Would you please clarify your question a little bit more ?

Comment: @the_dramatist i want make webhook